# Backbone: how to render myView into the DOM

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I hope this piece of code is enough to understand the problem.
The issue is the following,

1) I load myView for the first time,
2) If I click on `div#myId`, the function `myAction` is triggered just one time as expected.
3) If call the method `remove` for `rendering` another view, the functiom `myAction` is triggered two times.
4) Then if I repeat the step 3) the functiom `myAction` is triggered three times and so on.

What could be the problem?

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({

    // The DOM events specific to an item.
    events: {
        "click #myId" : "myAction"
    },

    myAction: function () {
        // some code
    },

    remove: function remove () 
    {
        $(this.el).html("");
    }

});
```

P.S.:
The DOM which is created to each render call is ok.

Comment: It's likely I'm misunderstanding, but why would your `click` event be triggered when the view is initially loaded? Are you manually triggering a `click` event somewhere?

Comment: I was not clear enough. Let me please explain. After I load the view for the first time, and then I click on the div#myId the function myAction is called just one time.

Answer (score 1):

usually the problem here is that you're in some state where you're re-rendering views over a pre-defined element over and over again, without properly destroying the view, resulting in 'zombie' views. If you've defined an `el` in your view, and keep rendering said view on it, you will end up duplicating your events.

in jQuery for an example if you do this a couple times:

```
$(document).bind('click',function(){ console.log("document.click"); });
$(document).bind('click',function(){ console.log("document.click"); });
$(document).bind('click',function(){ console.log("document.click"); });
```

it will fire the event three times.

Take a good look at how you initialize your views, and most importantly how you render/re-render them.

what you have to do in your remove method is more something along these lines

```
remove: function remove () 
{
    this.$el.remove();
    this.$el.unbind();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response very clear. But the issue persists. The strange thing is: if I run from js console the command `$el.unbind();` the event persist. If I run `$el.bind("click", function (){some code});` two events (BB + the new function) are triggered. It seems that bind works and unbind not.

Comment: update your original question with how you render myView into the DOM and I'll take a look

Comment: I think Vincent meant not to literally change your question title to "how to render myView into the DOM", but to explain in your question how it is you render myView into the DOM in the body of your question.